# How to target html 5 attribute "data-src" and replace with "src" with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

I'm trying to find a "best" method for dynamically loading files, and other elements by using the new html 5 "data-" attribute for storage and then removing it when needed.

## My Question:

How do I target the "data-" attribute and remove it thus leaving the remaining attribute name?

**For example, this:**

```
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" class="custom" data-href="css/mobile.css">
```

**Would turn into this:**

```
<!-- Custom CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" class="custom" href="css/mobile.css">
```

**Edit:** This entire experiment is for Responsive Design (ui/performance), I need to be able to load css files/ elements depending on device resolution. This will result in higher performance for smaller devices to prevent unnecessary data loading. I'm using [enquire.js plugin](http://wicky.nillia.ms/enquire.js/) (amazing btw), which allows you to have functions fire off when a media query is targeted. So in an effort to stay current I wanted to use the "data-" attribute to add/remove elements from the DOM depending on device resolution.

This tutorial by Christian Heilmann does just this:
http://christianheilmann.com/2012/12/19/conditional-loading-of-resources-with-mediaqueries/

I'm trying to combine his technique with enquire.js

Comment: yeah, don't. jQuery already has a getScript function for loading scripts, use that. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

Comment: But what about when it's a stylesheet I want to load conditionally? or an image?

Comment: those things behave VERY differently from script elements. for scripts, don't do this. If it's for stylesheets and images, we have a valid question, but then you should edit your post first.

Comment: Ok, I edited to change javascript example to css example

Comment: fair do, answered as a real answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you know how to get to your elements, enabling is a one liner:

```
$(element).attr("href", $(element).data("href"));
```

since the `data-href` does nothing, you don't need to remove it. Just mirror it as real `href` attribute. To invalidate, either invalidate the `href` attribute again:

```
$(element).attr("href", false);
```

or remove it altogether:

```
$(element).removeAttr("href");
```

And for `<img>` it's the same trick but with the string `"src"` instead of `"href"`

Comment: What about for other elements? I.E. a <p> tag? Would that be a completely different approach?

Comment: `<p>` has no source attributes (neither src nor href), so I don't know what you're asking about here. You can use this trick on any attribute in any element, but certain attributes have profound effects on the browser (like a src attribute on a `<script>` element that's located in the document `<head>`) and can't just be toggled on and off without persistent changes to the page.

Comment: This worked well, but instead the "false", I chose this: $(element).removeAttr("href");   --   Please see my *edit* to my question as you can better see what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: edited for both versions. Remember to flag an answer as correct if it was what you were looking for, for future SO visitors.

Comment: I'm still curious as if removing the "data-" all together and leaving the remaining "href" or whatever I want is possible? I think this would be ideal, for example: <img class="screen-only" data-src="images/computer00.jpg" data-alt="Computer" />, If I can simply remove and add them back it might be less code. Also, for the example of a something like <p class="screenonly">Hide this text when on mobile/tablet devices.</p>, what would be the best way to remove/add elements back like this that don't target attributes?

Comment: My main goal here is to conditionally load external files, images, videos, inline, and block elements depending a media query by either targeting "data-" or ".class" name *The smartest way*. You're answer has helped me greatly and I plan on checking it as the right answer but I'd like to expand on it a little further. This is what I have so far with your answer http://oneillwebs.com/conditional-loading/ (maximize and minimize window and have dev tools out to see content dynamically loading in and out of the markup).

Comment: you can't change a DOM attribute that way, no. While in the source code it's just a string, once it's a DOM node it's an attribute map and you can't "rename" the attribute.

Answer (score 3):

While I agree that it's worth questioning whether this is the correct way to approach this problem, from a technical stand-point this is how you access, remove, and add attributes on elements.

```
$('[data-attrName]').each(function() {
    var $el = $(this);
    var val = $el.attr('data-attrName');
    $el.removeAttr('data-attrName')
       .attr('attrName', val);
});
```

Comment: Checkout my *Edited* question up above and let me know if you think this is the correct approach or not. I'm all about learning the correct technique!

Answer (score 1):

To replace all `data-attributename` attributes with `attributename` can be accomplished simply by looping over the data object.

```
$(element).each(function() {
    var 
        el = $(this),
        data = el.data();

        $.each(data,function(key,value) { el.attr(key,value); });
});
```

I'll point out what others have already pointed out, though - I think you have decided that this is what you need to do to accomplish something, when it probably isn't what you should be doing.

Try asking a question whose answer will solve your actual problem, not asking a question whose answer will solve the problem that you are experiencing when you are using it to try and solve another problem....I'll understand if you don't understand that last sentence.

Comment: LOL, I understand what you mean completely.. I made an edit to my question so you can better understand what I'm trying to achieve. I've been digging into this topic for a solid month now gathering different techniques. I'm just trying to put them all together now in an easy to understand format.